# Reverse for 'add' with keyword arguments '{'product_id': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/<int:product_id>/']

Tags: html, python, django

Olá estou estudando Django e seguindo um tutorial cheguei a parte de adicionar um produto a minha sacola de compras, porém ao clicar no botão adicionar na sacola ele me retorna este erro:
[image: Imagem do erro na pagina web]

O Traceback me leva até esta parte do código:

[image: Imagem do traceback]

Meu código das urls.py está assim:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import cart_detail, cart_add, cart_remove

app_name = "cart"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", cart_detail, name="detail"),
    path("add/<int:product_id>/", cart_add, name="add"),
    path("remove/<int:product_id>/", cart_remove, name="remove"),
]
```

Meu cart_add que me redireciona para os detalhes do carrinho/sacola:

```
@require_POST
def cart_add(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)

    form = CartAddProductForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        cart.add(
            product=product, quantity=cd['quantity'], override_quantity=cd['override'],
        )

    return redirect('cart:detail')
```

E meu cart_detail está deste modo:

```
def cart_detail(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    return render(request, 'cart/sacola.html', {'cart': cart})
```

A ação de adicionar no carrinho/sacola está da seguinte forma no meu html:

```
<form class="form-group" action="{% url 'cart:add' product.id %}" method="POST">
    <p class="form-inline">
       {{ form.quantity.label_tag }}
       {% render_field form.quantity class+="form-control ml-sm-3" %}
       {{ form.override }}
    </p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Adicionar à Sacola">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro era que eu fiz a adição no carrinho por session e então tirei os produtos do meu site, porem na session ficou gravado o produto e acabava dando erro quando tentava acessar o carrinho.
Solução: deletar a session e então iniciar uma nova.

Comment: Bem vindo ao stack. Para melhor compartilhar a solução do seu problema é indicado que vc além do passo a passo, tbm poste o código da correção. Assim outras pessoas que tiverem o mesmo problema, poderão solucionar mais facilmente. Boa sorte